# Is there a word for every cinematographic techniques used by cameramen?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for every cinematographic techniques used by cameramen? I can only think of specific terms like "scene transitions" and "shots", but I am wondering if there's a word that include all of them and more. I need to know what such a word might be so I can do more research on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You're so close: **[cinematography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinematography)**.

Unrelated: "every" is a little misleading in your title. It seems to ask if *each* technique has a corresponding name, rather than to seek a word covering **all** techniques.